# Android Studio Always Using Proguard & Obfuscating Debug Build - Unable To Debug

Tags: android-studio, proguard

Using latest version of Android Studio 3.4.1 - and it seems that Android Studio is always using ProGuard even though I am setting **useProguard false**

```
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
```

This results in inability to debug and breakpoints not being hit as code is obfuscated.

**useProguard false** flag does not seem to work or do anything.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know how to resolve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#enable), the `minifyEnabled` option will enable "code shrinking, **obfuscation**, and optimization" (emphasis mine).

If you want to minimize but not obfuscate your debug build, you probably want to leave proguard enabled, but add the `-dontobfuscate` option to your `proguard-rules.txt` file. Or, more likely, create a `proguard-rules-debug.txt` that contains `-dontobfuscate`, and refer to that file from the `debug` section of your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing, separating proguard files into debug & release. I believe this is a recent change in Android Studio, only noticed this within a few recent updates.